# 502 bad gateway Nginx Node on AWS ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've read a lot of posts about fixing this, but so far nothing has worked, i'm out of ideas.

I have a Express Generator app, runs fine locally, doesn't run once on AWS Elastic Beanstalk site.

The EB runs as single instance, and the security group allows PORT 80 tcp from 0.0.0.0/0, and the rest is all default EB config (ip tables, nginx conf etc)

This is where i've got to...

1) Set node command to `npm start` to ensure it runs instead of `app.js`
2) updated the EC2 env `PATH` to add current `node`/`npm` to it
3) Ensured node port is running as 8081
4) checked node is actually running ok (on the box I can CURL both by IP and elastic beanstalk ULR successfully)

But from outside the box, the elastic beanstalk url returns 502 with this error..

```
2015/07/07 21:54:59 [error] 7883#0: *4 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 94.174.20.81, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "ae-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://ae-prod.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

Nginx config

```
upstream nodejs {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "";
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }


}
```

The IP tables on the box look like this..

```
$sudo iptables -t nat -L

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http redir ports 8080

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Any one got any ideas?

Comment: make sure your security group for your load balancer open to outside.

Comment: There is no load balancer, its a single instance.  Security groups all look ok...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it turned out my node application was failing to start due to missing dependencies. Check if you have a nodejs or npm process running on the host. If not go to

```
/var/app/current
```

and try to launch your app manually via `npm start`.  If it throws errors on start or fails to start up these could be the reason for the 502.